# How can I generate a PartialView for each click of a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a button that I want to generate a PartialView for each click, I was searching in Google, but I couldn't find any result, I need to discovery how can I do that.

So, here is my button:

```html
<div style="padding-bottom: 15px;">
  <button id="btnNovaFormaPagamento" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Nova Forma de Pagamento</button>
</div>
```

I need that this button generate this PartialView who name is _DetalheVendas.cshtml for each click

```html
<div class="panel panel-default text-uppercase hidden-xs" id="frmDetalhesVenda">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div id="divFormaPagamento" class="col-md-4 text-primary">
                    <label id="lblFormaPagamento" class="control-label">Formas de Pagamento</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="ddlFormaPagamento">
                        <option value="0">Selecione</option>
                        <option value="1">Cartão</option>
                        <option value="2">Cheque</option>
                        <option value="3">Boleto</option>
                        <option value="4">Dinheiro</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div id="divOpcaoPagamento" class="col-md-4 text-primary hide">
                    <label id="lblOpcaoPagamento" class="control-label">Opções de Pagamento</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="ddlOpcaoPagamento">
                        <option value="0">Selecione</option>
                        <option value="1">Débito</option>
                        <option value="2">Crédito à Vista</option>
                        <option value="3">Crédito Parcelado</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div id="divFormaPagamentoCartao" class="text-primary hide">
                <div class="col-md-12 text-primary" style="padding-top: 10px;">
                    <div id="divAdministradoras" class="col-md-2 text-primary">
                        <label id="lblAdministradoras" class="control-label">Administradoras</label>
                        <select class="col-md-2 form-control" id="ddlAdministradoras">
                            <option>Santander</option>
                            <option>Rede</option>
                            <option>GetNet</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div id="divBandeiras" class="col-md-2 text-primary">
                        <label id="lblBandeiras" class="control-label">Bandeiras</label>
                        <select class="col-md-2 form-control" id="ddlBandeiras">
                            <option>Mastercard</option>
                            <option>Cielo</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div id="divAutorizacao" class="col-md-2 text-primary">
                        <label id="lblAutorizacao" class="control-label">Autorização</label>
                        <input id="txtUltimosNumerosCartao" type="text" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="divPrimeirosNumerosCartao" class="col-md-2 text-primary">
                        <label id="lblPrimeirosNumerosCartao" class="control-label">XXXX</label>
                        <input id="txtPrimeirosNumerosCartao" type="text" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 text-primary" style="padding-top: 10px;">
                    <div id="divValorCompraCartao" class="col-md-2 text-primary">
                        <label id="lblValorCompraCartao" class="control-label">Valor Compra</label>
                        <input id="txtValorCompraCartao" type="text" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="divQtdParcelasCartao" class="col-md-2 text-primary">
                        <label id="lblQtdParcelasCartao" class="control-label">Qtd Parcelas</label>
                        <input id="txtQtdParcelasCartao" type="text" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="divDataPrimeiroVencimentoCartao" class="col-md-2 text-primary">
                        <label id="lblDataPrimeiroVencimentoCartao" class="control-label">Data 1º Vencimento</label>
                        <input id="txtDataPrimeiroVencimentoCartao" type="text" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="divTitularCartao" class="col-md-3 text-primary">
                        <label id="lblTitularCartao" class="control-label">Titular do Cartão</label>
                        <input id="txtTitularCartao" type="text" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="divFormaPagamentoCheque" class="text-primary hide">
                <div class="col-md-12 text-primary" style="padding-top: 10px;">
                    <div id="divBanco" class="col-md-2 text-primary">
                        <label id="lblBanco" class="control-label">Banco</label>
                        <input id="txtBanco" type="text" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="divAgencia" class="col-md-2 text-primary">
                        <label id="lblAgencia" class="control-label">Agência</label>
                        <input id="txtAgencia" type="text" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="divConta" class="col-md-2 text-primary">
                        <label id="lblConta" class="control-label">Conta</label>
                        <input id="txtConta" type="text" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="divValorCompraCheque" class="col-md-2 text-primary">
                        <label id="lblValorCompraCheque" class="control-label">Valor Compra</label>
                        <input id="txtValorCompraCheque" type="text" class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                    <div id="divQtdParcelasCheque" class="col-md-2 text-primary">
                        <label id="lblQtdParcelasCheque" class="control-label">Qtd Parcelas</label>
                        <input id="txtQtdParcelasCheque" type="text" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 text-primary" style="padding-top: 10px;">
                    <div id="divNumeroCheque" class="col-md-2 text-primary">
                        <label id="lblNumeroCheque" class="control-label">Número Cheque</label>
                        <input id="txtNumeroCheque" type="text" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="divDataPrimeiroVencimentoCheque" class="col-md-2 text-primary">
                        <label id="lblDataPrimeiroVencimentoCheque" class="control-label">Data 1º Vencimento</label>
                        <input id="txtDataPrimeiroVencimentoCheque" type="text" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="divTitularCheque" class="col-md-3 text-primary">
                        <label id="lblTitularCheque" class="control-label">Titular do Cheque</label>
                        <input id="txtTitularCheque" type="text" class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                    <div id="divCPFCheque" class="col-md-2 text-primary">
                        <label id="lblCPFCheque" class="control-label">CPF</label>
                        <input id="txtCPFCheque" type="text" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="divFormaPagamentoBoleto" class="text-primary hide">
                <div class="col-md-12 text-primary" style="padding-top: 10px;">
                    <div id="divValorCompraBoleto" class="col-md-2 text-primary">
                        <label id="lblValorCompraBoleto" class="control-label">Valor Compra</label>
                        <input id="txtValorCompraBoleto" type="text" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="divQtdParcelasBoleto" class="col-md-2 text-primary">
                        <label id="lblQtdParcelasBoleto" class="control-label">Qtd Parcelas</label>
                        <input id="txtQtdParcelasBoleto" type="text" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="divDataPrimeiroVencimentoBoleto" class="col-md-2 text-primary">
                        <label id="lblDataPrimeiroVencimentoBoleto" class="control-label">Data 1º Vencimento</label>
                        <input id="txtDataPrimeiroVencimentoBoleto" type="text" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 text-primary" style="padding-top: 10px;">
                    <div id="divCPFBoleto" class="col-md-2 text-primary">
                        <label id="lblCPFBoleto" class="control-label">CPF</label>
                        <input id="txtCPFBoleto" type="text" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="divTitularBoleto" class="col-md-2 text-primary">
                        <label id="lblTitularBoleto" class="control-label">Titulat do Boleto</label>
                        <input id="txtTitularBoleto" type="text" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="divDataNascimento" class="col-md-3 text-primary">
                        <label id="lblDataNascimento" class="control-label">Data Nascimento</label>
                        <input id="txtDataNascimento" type="text" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="divFormaPagamentoDinheiro" class="text-primary hide">
                <div class="col-md-12 text-primary" style="padding-top: 10px;">
                    <div id="divValorCompraDinheiro" class="col-md-2 text-primary">
                        <label id="lblValorCompraDinheiro" class="control-label">Valor Compra</label>
                        <input id="txtValorCompraDinheiro" type="text" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="divDataPagamentoDinheiro" class="col-md-3 text-primary">
                        <label id="lblDataPagamentoDinheiro" class="control-label">Data Pagamento</label>
                        <input id="txtDataPagamentoDinheiro" type="text" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Your example only contains html and no page-loading-logic or jQuery / javascript.

Comment: Also, please include what your view model looks like.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.